# Каким образом работает данный код?

Tags: c++, стандарт

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему и как работает следующий код:

```
std::vector<int> v <%1, 2, 3, 4, 5%>;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size();++i) {
    std::cout << v<:i:> << std::endl;
}
```

Самое забавное, что расположение `%,:` должно быть строгим, как в коде.
Условно после точки с запятой, компилятор выдает ошибку, так как подстраивает в --> `std::vector<int> v < % 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

См. [**диграфы**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A1%D0%B8)).

Приведенный вами код эквивалентен следующему:

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size();++i) {
    std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Как и почему он работает, объяснять не надо? :)

Comment: От души, спасибо.